¿Quisiera saber cómo es que puedo obtener el ultimo id de persona para mi codigo?
me encuentro trabajando en una base de datos oracle database sql
Y cómo sabran no tiene autoincremento, por lo que programe un trigger.
Tengo dos tablas
Persona y tipoPersona, las cuales tienen un atributo en común, IDPERSONA, el cual me gustaria recabar de Persona para insertar en tipopersona desde java
Mi codigo es el siguiente, la sentencia de recuperación fue una de varias formas que he intentado.
¿Alguna idea de cómo podria recabar el ultimo ID insertado?
public void insertarUsuario(String nombres, String primerapellido, String segundoApellido, Date FechaNacimiento, String Nacionalidad)throws SQLException{
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conectar = con.getDBConnection();

            //Insertar en la tabla persona
            String query1 = "INSERT INTO PERSONA (NOMBRES,PRIMERAPELLIDO,SEGUNDOAPELLIDO,FECHANACIMIENTO) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conectar.prepareStatement(query1);
            stmt.setString(1,nombres);
            stmt.setString(2, primerapellido);
            stmt.setString(3,segundoApellido);
            stmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(FechaNacimiento.getTime()));
            stmt.executeUpdate();

            //Inserción en la tabla tipopersona
            ResultSet rs = conectar.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT MAX(IDPERSONA) AS ULTIMO_ID FROM PERSONA");
            int idPersona = rs.getInt("ULTIMO_ID");
          
            String query2 = "INSERT INTO TIPOPERSONA(IDPERSONA,NACIONALIDAD,TIPOPERSONA) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmn = conectar.prepareStatement(query2);
            stmn.setInt(1,idPersona);
            stmn.setString(2,Nacionalidad);
            stmn.setString(3, "U");

            System.out.println("Usuario insertado correctamente con el ID: "+idPersona);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error al insertar al Usuario ");
        }
    }


Buenas, Kalid, bienvenido al sitio. Aquí te indican una posible solución a tu problema.
